# Centroid of Areas bounded by some Curves

Tags: integration

I was looking for the centroid of the area bounded by the curves $ y = x^2 - 4$ and $ y = 2x - x^2$

My work:

I visualize the problem like this:

[image]

Using the vertical strip $dx$ and remembering that the centroid $C(\bar x, \bar y)$ can be found by the formula:

$$A \bar x = \int x_c \space dA$$ and $$A \bar y = \int y_c \space dA$$

Now getting the $A$, $x_c$, $dA$, and $y_c:$

To get area $A$:

$$A = \int_{-1} ^2 (y_{upper} - y_{lower}) dx$$
Then: $$A = \int_{-1} ^2 ((2x-x^2) - (x^2 - 4)) dx = 9$$

To get $x_c:$
$$x_c = x$$

To get $dA:$
$$dA = y \space dx$$
$$dA = (y_{upper} - y_{lower}) \space dx$$
$$dA = ((2x-x^2) - (x^2 - 4)) \space dx$$
$$dA = (-2x^2+2x + 4) \space dx$$

To get $ y_c:$
$$y_c  = I \space don't \space know$$

We got all we need to find, and substituting it to the formula shown below:
$$A \bar x = \int x_c \space dA$$
$$9 \bar x = \int_{-1} ^2 x \space ((2x-x^2) - (x^2 - 4)) \space dx$$
$$9 \bar x = \int_{-1} ^2 x \space (-2x^2+2x + 4) \space dx$$
$$x_c = \frac{1}{2}$$

Looking now for the $y_c:$

$$A \bar y = \int y_c \space dA$$

At this point, I'm stuck, because I couldn't decide how will I get the expression for $y_c$ and $dA.$ The figure is difficult to look at if I were to find $y_c$ and $dA.$

How to get the $y_c$? I got the $x_c = \frac{1}{2}.$

Teach me how to get $y_c,$ and my centroid $C(\bar x, \bar y)$ will be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it's just $\left(\frac{2+(-1)}{2},\frac{0+(-3)}{2}\right)$ or $(0.5,-1.5)$.

Comment: Please show me how you get the $y_c$...TThanks!

Comment: @Palautot Ka I know the following way $\frac{1}{18}\int\limits_{-1}^2((2x-x^2)^2-(x^2-4)^2)dx$, but I think it's better to use symmetry.

Comment: I'm not comfortable of getting $y_c$ that way. It's good. But I do know that to get the $\bar y, $ I need to use the formula $A \bar y = \int y_c \space dA $  because I'm comfortable with it. My problem is I don't know how to get the $y_c$ and $dA.$ Teach me how to get $y_c$ and $dA.$ Thanks!

Comment: @Palautot Ka I remember it should be  the following. $Ay_c=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_a^b(f(x)^2-g(x)^2)dx$. In our case $f(x)=2x-x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2-4$.

Comment: Ah! You used the formula to find the $\bar y$?

Comment: @Palautot Ka Yes, of course! I think the formula is $Ay_c=\int\limits_a^b\frac{y_{upper}+y_{lower}}{2}dA$